# Integrating Halogen into Yesod build process

Tags: haskell, yesod, purescript, halogen

I would like to put together a webapp using Yesod for the back end and Halogen (PureScript) for the front end. Is there a best practice for having an integrated build process for the two?  In particular is there a good way of having a single build step that will run both the Haskell and Purescript compilers and get the outputs from each into the same tree?

Comment: We use a lot of custom Nix for this. Though I notice that when I google "PureScript Bazel" I get some interesting results.

Comment: Related: https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod/issues/1377